# CS50 pset5 Speller [2022] - " :( program is free of memory errors"

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

I get error ":( program is free of memory errors valgrind tests failed; see log for more information."

Here is my code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//Declare variables
unsigned int word_count;
unsigned int hash_value;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    hash_value = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[hash_value];


    // Go in link list
    while (cursor != 0)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    unsigned long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        total += tolower(word[i]);
    }
    return total % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    // it would be null if cant be open
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open %s\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // Declare variable words
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    //Scan dictionary for strings up until EOF
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //copy wordds into node
        strcpy(n->word, word);
        hash_value = hash(word);
        n->next = table[hash_value];
        table[hash_value] = n;
        word_count++;

    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (word_count > 0)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        if (cursor == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are the errors in valgrind check50:
program is free of memory errors valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.
Here is ERR log:
56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 80)

And 80th line code is:

```
 while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`unload` will free one index and return to speller because of this `if (cursor == NULL)` block. The last node in an index should set cursor to NULL, so function is done. That conditional should be eliminated. There is really no condition in `unload` that should return false.